# How can I make Google Maps treat the current map view as the default search area, and not always default to my current location?

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to make Google Maps treat the current map view as the default search area, and not always default to my current location?

I'm making plans for a vacation in Europe, but if I'm viewing a European city in Google Maps and search on "Car rental," Google Maps always jumps back to my current location in NYC.

(I know I can search on "Car rental in Rome, Italy" as a workaround, but what I want to do is change the default so that I don't need to add "in Rome, Italy" every time.)  I'm using Google Maps either on Windows, or with the iOS app.